# How to slow 12 VDC motor for power windows in a car?

Tags: voltage

I installed power window motors in a classic car and they run way too fast I cannot change the gearing is it possible to reduce the power to slow down the motors?

Comment: What kind of motors are these? Are you running them straight off the electrical system?

Comment: I dont know there are no marking on them yes they are straight off the electrical system

Comment: Yes. But you need to know more about the motors. Can you measure the current? Are they available on-line? Do you know what kind of car they came out of?

Comment: A straight up resistor in series? A few ohms and several watt power rating?

Comment: There were power window kits available that "bolted" over the shaft after removing the original handle. But if you got a "universal" kit meant for newer cars then the kit was sized for newer windows and seal...

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please note that it's much easier for others to respond to your question if you supply as much information on your problem as possible. In your case pictures or datasheets of the motors and gears might be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You can, but it will also reduce torque and could stall the motor if it falls too low. What kind of classic car has power windows anyways? I thought classic cars were...classic?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Im looking to solve a problem Wanted modern convenience in an older car

Answer (score 2):

The current required by the motor will vary over a wide range and reducing the voltage (with some form of regulator) will only work to some extent.
The motor may have a 10:1 ratio (or more) of starting current to moving current so using any form of series resistance is basically futile. Sooner or later your motor will stall.

Since what you want to do is control the speed of the motor you have to sense either the rotation of the motor or the linear travel of the window movement arms.

You have several choices:

1. Use some sort of position sensor (resistor or pulse position encoder) in a closed loop servo. This is probably beyond your requirements.
2. A PWM controller run open loop. This might be your best solution with the most simple implementation.

As an example of #2 you could use a simple DC motor controller like [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-12-24-36-48V-60A-PWM-Motor-Speed-Controller-CW-CCW-Reversible-Switch/163328680990) which provides a PWM drive **with reverse switches** (I assume you want both up and down control of the window).

[image]

This type of open loop PWM controller can still allow your motor to pull startup current and will give you the ability to effectively dial back the speed, though the speed will NOT be regulated.
If you set this to 50% duty cycle it would be almost identical to driving the motor with 6V instead of 12V. The PWM control will probably only work between about 50% and 100% duty cycle as the motor does need to provide the initial torque requirements.

The second major advantage I would assume is you don't have to build and test a solution.

Comment: How would you make this work in both directions?

Comment: @hacktastical ….if you could read you'd notice that this unit has a reversing switch …..for just the purpose of changing direction so the window could go up or down....looks purpose built for the OPs need.

Comment: Got it, ok. Now the challenge would be to make it work with a vintage type switch...

Comment: @hacktastical Given it has a switch and the car never had electric windows, that would appear out of scope for the question.

Comment: @JackCreasey If you were polite you'd realise that adding in gratuitous abuse probably is less than more helpful. If I could think I may realise it too :-).

Comment: But, +1 anyway :-). It looks like as good a solution as is liable to be achievable without some advanced control playing.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a mechanical issue.  It sounds like either the motors are a misfit for the job at hand... Or the linkage is a misfit.

I don't know where you got these motors, but I would hope they are power window motors out of a car, of such an age that they are mechanically powered and not electronically controlled.  These motors incorporate the gear-downs you are looking for. Further, many of them don't turn a shaft; they swing a lever.  This lever needs to be mechanically linked to your window mechanism.

**These mechanical issues are show-stoppers**.  There is nothing you can do with electrical wizardry that can correct for problems here.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge with using any sort of a one-quadrant PWM approach is that the motor runs in two directions. So instead of being wired at the motor, the PWM chopper has to be wired somewhere between the master switch panel and the supply fuse. This isn't so easy considering how these switch panels are built up. I consider this impractical, given the idea of not messing about too much with a classic car.

Adding a series resistor on each motor would be simpler. How to choose a value? Measure the motor current. If you measure 4A, the motor will present about a 3 ohm nominal load while running. Add a resistor about the same as that value to slow the motor by 50%, so 3 ohms or so. The rating should be about 50W to be safe, as the motor can draw a lot more at the end of its travel.

You can get adjustable ceramic power resistors to tweak the current. Example: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Ohmite/D50K3R0E?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtbXrIkmrvidHIgCu07YBurrqV1pEdYAB8%3D

Looks a lot like a rheostat, which is exactly what it is. Old-school motor control.

One last thing. Make sure the resistor is thermally insulated from the stuff surrounding it as it can get hot.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Looking at the power resistor (the example you gave) how do you adjust it?

Comment: The side of the resistor has exposed wire coil. See the collar that's attached to it? That's a wiper that can slide up and down over the resistor so you can set the value.

Comment: +1 MAy have issues wity stalling wth series R but not worthy of the -1 some turkey awarded it uncommented.

Comment: I mulled the idea of using an NTC: if the motor stalls (locked rotor) the current would increase and heat the NTC, which would increase the motor current once more as its resistance would go down. Maybe enough to clear the stall? Just a thought.